# C#で写真や画像から文字検出するならどんな手段がありますか？

Tags: c#

写真や画像から文字検出（日本語）するのに適した手段はありますか？
写真や画像中に大体何文字あるか判断したいと思っています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tesseract.NetというOCRライブラリを使うのが手軽そうです。
http://shirakamisauto.hatenablog.com/entry/2016/01/28/121402

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
お手軽だったので色々な漫画の１ページに使ってみました。
どうやら絵の部分も文字として認識してしまうようで
実際のセリフよりもかなり多めに文字が抽出されるようですね。

Answer (score 1):

OCR(光学文字認識)は主として印刷された文書の文字を読み取ることを対象にしています。Tesseract.Netの精度は背景に線が入る程度のノイズでかなり悪化しますので、もし被写体や構図を限定しない風景写真のようなものを入力として想定しているのであれば相当な数の誤検出や検出漏れが発生すると思われます。

仮に読み取る対象が決まっているのであれば、OpenCVなどの画像処理ライブラリでテンプレートマッチングを行い、文字を検出する領域を抽出してからOCR処理を行うことで大幅に精度を上げることができると思います。

Comment: お世話になっております。
ご指摘の通りTesseract.Netでは精度に欠けました。
結局、柔軟性の高いものを作るには色々な壁があると実感し、
画像判定部分は人力で行うことにしました。

ただ、読み取る対象が決まっている場合の処理は非常に参考になりました。
ありがとうございます。またよろしくお願い致します。